# Importing World of Warcraft models into Unity

Tags: unity, models, importing

I'm following some tutorials to create a simple game with Unity in order to learn, and I would like to enhance my learning experience by adding World of Warcraft models. Don't worry, this is all just for learning and won't see public eyes in any way.
I downloaded a model viewer and I can export textures and animation from WoW with it, but when importing into Unity I'm having some problems.

Which extension should I export the model to, and what is the process I should follow in order to have an object with a model I just exported?

I'm really new to Unity, so any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

I would say you should export to FBX. That format includes animations and various other info. You could probably export to other types but Im pretty sure most use FBX. Once you import it, you will have to specify the texture for it so you will have to take the texture your exporter gives you and feed that into unity.

Also, you said you are just learning but I would say to be careful about using those models. I don't know for sure, but I would think blizzard might not like it. There are tons of free models you could use online that work with unity. Their asset store has a lot of free stuff that works just fine and imports ready to go.

Comment: He's not planning to release them, why isn't blizzard going to like that? Lol

Comment: @animaonline It is unclear if OP is planning to release the project they are working on or not. The safest option is to make sure they are aware that publishing anything with Blizzard's assets (even if its a free game) might end up in trouble.

Comment: Then I suggest you have your sight checked, then re-read the OPs question one more time.

Comment: Lol weird this is getting comments 8 years later. I stated in my answer that I knew he was just learning, I was just saying to be careful as I didn't know know anything about Blizz policies regarding it. Some companies do consider any usage of their models against their terms or 'reverse engineering' and are against any form of usage regardless if learning or not.